# JS - iterate through an object and change its attribute values?

Tags: javascript

Suppose below I wanted to change 'valid' for 'a','b' and 'c' equal to true. For the object foo.

```
var foo = {
    a: {
        valid: false,
        required: true
    },
    b: {
        valid: false,
        required: true
    },
    c: {
        valid: false,
        required: true
    }
};

for (var key in foo) {
    var obj = foo[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            //how can I assign valid to true here?
        };

    }
```

Comment: `obj[prop].valid = true` ? You already know how to access object properties in a loop and how to perform an assignment, so I don't get what the issue is.

Comment: @squint That doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/9ju25fff/

Comment: @BDillan: He means `key`, not `prop`, in the outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Just do this:

```
for( var key in foo ) {
    foo[key].valid = true;
}
```

Or, if you're concerned that some code in your page may have extended `Object.prototype` with an enumerable property, you can do this instead:

```
for( var key in foo ) {
    if( foo.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        foo[key].valid = true;
    }
}
```

But nobody should ever extend `Object.prototype` with an enumerable property. That breaks all kinds of code. It's very unlikely that this would be an issue you'd need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gfezqo5r/3/)

```
for (var key in foo) {
    var obj = foo[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("valid")) { //checks if "valid" exists
            if (!obj.valid) { //if valid=false change to true, else ignore
                obj.valid = true;
            };
        }

    }
}
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: You're not using `prop`